# Node Voltage: Why must I have to let unreferenced node to be going outward current?

Tags: current

[image: node incoming]

Why do I need to make V1, unreferenced node, outgoing current for i(a) to get the correct answer? why can't I follow the given current direction and use it to calculate the correct voltage at that node?

[image: node voltage]

Comment: It's common practice to sum all currents away from a node and equate to zero. That avoids transcription errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter. If you make the arrow go the other direction, your answer will just be \$i_a \text{(new)}=-i_a \text{(old)} \$

Comment: But how come I get different voltage value if I find voltage difference from 50v to V1 and V1 to 50v?

Comment: Oh. I see what you did. Mathematically you need to say "all the currents coming into this node sum to zero". If you write it that way, you need to plop it on the other side of the equal sign instead of the zero.

Comment: ie "all of the currents coming into this node are equal to the current going out of that branch"

Comment: Remember that some of the currents "coming in" to the node are going to be negative. You're just making the math deal with that detail for you.

Comment: wow Thanks Daniel, you changed the whole world for me just right now. I can't believe that I never saw that logic of (incoming) = (outgoing). I thought just by multiplying negative to the incoming current, sum would be automatically satisfied. I just realized that what I calculated was general direction of i (a) and never encounted incoming of that i (a)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff's_circuit_laws Don't get caught up in the math notation, but make sure you understand this and what it means.